# Asus t100 not turning on

Tags: windows-8.1, tablet

I have an Asus T100 transformer tablet with Windows 8.1. I plugged it in to charge and now it won't turn on. The red charging light is on, and if I hold the power button in for about 10 seconds, this light goes off and comes back on when I release the button; however nothing else happens. I've had this problem a few times before, but all I ever had to do was hold the power button in until the Asus logo appeared.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have an ASUS WD11 tablet running Win8 and experienced a similar issue. I can't remember if the solution was to try another charger all together or to use my phone's USB to AC charger, which is why I'm posting as a comment. My charger was showing signs of life too, illuminating the red charging light. Still, it wasn't until I tried using one of the two mentioned chargers that my ASUS tablet would accept and retain a charge to boot.

Comment: You likely can't without sending it to ASUS.  You can try another charger or if the tablet offers a user replaceable battery a new battery.

Comment: If it's into warranty, have it RMA'd

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible causes for this problem that can be fixed on your own. I have experienced both (not in the order presented below :-) ).

Most likely cause in general is **battery exhausted and not recharging** due to insufficient power supply voltage. Most micro-USB chargers are rated for 1.0A current; the Asus T100 requires 2.0A.

Due to Li-Ion battery design, when it is just "topping off", the Asus will require less than 1A of current. Therefore, practically any charger will be able to top off the Asus.

But when it is markedly discharged, the Asus will attempt to suck the full 2A of current, and this will drop the input voltage a bit. If the power supply is not the original one, and is only rated for 1.0A, the voltage drop will be enough to drive the voltage outside the battery controller's "comfort zone", and the red LED light will power on (since current is being drawn) -- but the battery won't recharge, as the controller won't allow it. With some aftermarket chargers you will notice the light on the charger going off, then on, then off, continuously.

PC USB ports also sometimes have an overcurrent protection, so that they won't charge a flat-batteried Asus even if they will allow it to top off.

Solution is of course to use the original Asus power supply, or a power supply with a higher **current** rating, typically 2.1A (be careful; higher **current** ratings will not damage the Asus, but higher **voltage** ratings, rare as they are, definitely will). You want to have exactly 5.0V (the USB standard) and equal or more than 2.0A. Standard smartphone chargers are 1.0A or less, and will definitely not work, *even if they might work when the Asus isn't completely flat*. Some tablet chargers are 2.1A and will work.

The other possibility is a faulty battery connection. The battery has an internal connector covered by a transparent yellow adhesive protection film, but there are reports that the connector might sometimes not be plugged all the way in. Unless you're very very careful, this will void the warranty: insert a guitar pick or a thin hard **plastic** sliver between the bottom of the tablet and the screen. Drive it gently all around, and you will see the catches snap open. The cover must be slid out towards the USB power plug; do not force it open there, or you might damage the USB connector. Once removed the shell, you will see the battery (a double silvered flat package) and four connectors. The battery one is covered by an adhesive film. Try picking loose the adhesive film; the connector shouldn't move. You can use a hard plastic sliver to pry it loose and re-seat it until it clicks, then replace the adhesive film. When putting back the cover, first slide it over the USB connectors; don't simply press it in place. *After* the connectors are slotted in the back cover, then you can press the cover in place (you can just snap each catch closed by pinching screen and cover together with thumb and forefinger in corrispondence of each catch).

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question but it remains on the top of SERP so here was my solution for the *Asus T100T* which had identical problem as yours.

---

**FYI:** The LED next to the power buttons indicates battery status.

White = fully charged

Orange = charging

---

You must hold the power button for good **30 seconds** to fully reset it.

Then press the power button again for 2-3 seconds and it will boot up showing the ASUS logo and automatically start Windows repair mode.

Answer (score 1):

My Asus T100 TAF (running Win 10) had a power issue when it came out of the box. It shut off randomly.
My symptoms : no problems while attached to the dock. If i undocked it, after a while it would randomly shut off and i would get no message regarding an innapropriate shut-off when i would turn it back on. When moving the tablet around or slightly bending it the power stayed strong. That led me to think the problem was linked to software, drivers or firmware.

Actions i took: updated winflash then updated the bios. Turned off secure boot. After that i also turned off the DEP. From then on the problem never occured again.
Besides it fixed also a secondary issue that appeared when installing apps to SD card.

I'm not suggesting this is a fix for every similiar issue, but it worked for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The following just worked for me:

1. Press and hold the “Volume Down” button, then press and hold the “Power” button.
2. Continue to hold both buttons until the screen powers on. Once you see an image on the screen, you can let go of the buttons.
3. The image which popped up was the classic black & blue BIOS screen asking for a password. I had to enter "password" which I presume is the factory default. The device should power on normally.

However the source I got it from (below) had slightly different instructions, so might be worth trying this as well:

1. Press and hold the “Volume Down” button, then press and hold the “Power” button.
2. Continue to hold both buttons until the screen powers on. Once you see an image on the screen, let go of the buttons.
3. Press the “Volume Up” button. The device should power on normally.

*Source: https://www.technipages.com/asus-transformer-pad-wont-turn-on-fix*

Answer (score 0):

I put scotch tape on the bottom where you hold it when it is not on the keyboard. Problem solved. I believe it is a moisture issue with the contacts and the aluminum frame. It is probably why the hinge design was changed.